# List with icons in not fitting to left margin? there is a space

Tags: html, css, list, space, paragraph

html

```
 <ul class="social">
 <li><a class="html5" href="#html5"></a></li>
 <li><a class="twitter" href="#twitter"></a></li>
 <li><a class="facebook" href="#facebook"></a></li>
 <ul>
```

Everything works, but not fitted to margin? I need it flush like the rest of my page...any advice?

css

```
.social ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.social li
{
display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the fiddle the `<ul>` still has the default 40px of left-padding and 16px of top/bottom margin, so just add `margin: 0; padding: 0;` to the unordered list. Every browser adds this padding/margin to lists - I'd suggest using a CSS reset, so you can explicitly reset the default browser styling for each element. [Look at this](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) for more info

Secondly `inline-block` elements are [white-space dependent](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) so if you comment out, or delete the white-space in your mark-up (between the `<li>`) the horizontal space between the images will be reduced.

**Edit:** It [*does display*](http://jsfiddle.net/nxn9S/5/) inline horizontally .. the reason why `margin: 0; padding: 0;` didn't take effect is because `.social ul` implies the unordered list is a descendant of some element with the class .social when it isn't, so the default padding/margin remained.

Answer (score 1):

In the CSS, you are trying to set margin and padding to "0" but since your path is wrong

-> .social ul

**I think it should be:**

-> ul.social

Comment: No, you would still need the rest in your example,

".social li
{
display: inline-block;
}"

. But that will still be a problem in ie7.

If you instead set the 
.social li{
display:inline;
}
.social li a{
display:block;
//here you can also add padding or margin to make the right spaces
}